# Why can't I upgrade MySQL in Xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I followed this guide https://superuser.com/a/860604

However, when I run mysql it fall and get me error:

> 2017-12-15 12:24:58 10592 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.column_stats: expected column 'min_value' at position 3 to have type varbinary(255), found type varchar(255).
>
> 2017-12-15 12:24:58 10592 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.column_stats: expected column 'max_value' at position 4 to have type varbinary(255), found type varchar(255).

What's going wrong?

Comment: Looks like it's a known bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42100

Comment: Did you run the Upgrade?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no. it's can't start, because him can't connect to mysql server

Comment: You are running the upgrade from a Admin account I assume? Or are you using XAMPP on linux?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes.

Comment: Yes Linux or Yes using an admin account on Windows?

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry. Windows admin

Answer (score 3):

This might be old, but this should help most people troubling right now. I'm also moving from MariaDB 10.1.x (provided default by XAMPP), and upgrading to MariaDB 10.2.18(their latest version of 10.2.x).

Assuming you done correctly, until line 9 from your source.

Then simply comment this in **mysql/bin/my.ini**

```
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The database "mysql" schema may have changed after the upgrade.
mysql expects two colums to be of different type.

Dump mysql database as backup and change those columns:

```
alter table `column_stats` drop column `min_value`;
alter table `column_stats` drop column `max_value`;
alter table `column_stats` add column `min_value` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL AFTER `column_name`;
alter table `column_stats` add column `max_value` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL AFTER `min_value`;
```

Comment: After doing a large-ish import into the MariaDB on Xampp, I had a 22GB(!) .err file.. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was

```
use mysql;
alter table column_stats modify column max_value varbinary(255);
alter table column_stats modify column min_value varbinary(255);
```

That changed the error message to

`InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade`

So I ran `mysql_upgrade` and everything seems normal again.

Comment: I have no idea when or how this occurred, but my log was just crushed by it, that's the only reason I noticed.  This fix was perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE` is not necessary.
Running `mysql_upgrade` should be enough. It performs the necessary `ALTER` commands.

Comment: Because this is a reply to an **OLD** question, without any Version info on which MySQL is being upgraded  ..........,  I feel the need to add [mysql_upgrade — Deprecated, from **8.3**; Performs No Tasks and Exits with Status 0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/mysql-upgrade.html): "The MySQL server performs the upgrade tasks previously handled by mysql_upgrade . Consequently, mysql_upgrade is unneeded and is deprecated; **expect it to be removed in a future version of MySQL**. Because mysql_upgrade no longer performs upgrade tasks, it exits with status 0 unconditionally."

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35761170)